# Unique in ModelForm, how to get back to the form with error message?

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have found some posts about more or less the same situation like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141030/djangos-modelform-unique-together-validation) or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923826/django-how-do-i-validate-unique-together-from-within-the-model), but I was not able to adapt any of these to my situation.
What I would like is to return to my form with a warning if the user try to create another model with the same name of one already stored by himself in the db.
I would like to use Django built in facilities as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), but I need some advices to change my code: could you help me, please?
My code follows:

- **models.py**

  ```
  class ShapeFile(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      srid = models.ForeignKey(SpatialRefSys)
      model_definition = models.OneToOneField(ModelDefinition)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
      color_table = models.ManyToManyField(ColorTable)
      file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
      class Meta:
          unique_together = ('name', 'user')
  ```
- **forms.py**

  ```
  class UploadForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = ShapeFile
          fields = ('name','srid','file','color_table')
          widgets = {'srid': TextInput()}
  ```
- **views.py**

  ```
  @login_required
  def index(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
          if form.is_valid():
              req = request.POST
              sridVal = form.cleaned_data['srid'].pk
              shpVal = form.cleaned_data['name']

              # The final table name is something like 'mutant_celeryPy2_123_salzburg_lc'
              end_table_name = request.user.username + "_" + shpVal + '_lc'

              # Creates a table, otherwise return the retrieved one
              model_def, created = ModelDefinition.objects.get_or_create(
                  app_label='celeryPy2',
                  object_name=end_table_name,
                  defaults=dict(
                     bases=(BaseDefinition(base=GeoModel),),
                     fields=(GeometryFieldDefinition(name='the_geom', srid=sridVal),
                             SmallIntegerFieldDefinition(name='cat'),)
                  )
              )
              obj = form.save(commit=False)
              obj.user = request.user
              obj.model_definition = model_def
              obj.save()
              messages.success(request, 'Shapefile upload succesful!')
              return HttpResponse('Stored!')
          else:
              print "Upload shapefile form is invalid!!!"
      else:
          form = UploadForm()

      return render_to_response('celeryPy2/index.html',
                                {'form': form,},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```

If I login as user1 and fill the form, let's suppose with name 'myshape', when I submit it I get the "Stored!" message: everything fine, model user1_myshape_lc is created.
If I re-login with the same user1 and try to store other data with field name set at 'myshape' as before I correctly get an exception:

```
    Exception Type: IntegrityError at /celeryPy2/main
    Exception Value: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "celeryPy2_shapefile_model_definition_id_key"
    DETAIL:  Key (model_definition_id)=(154) already exists.
```

How to get back my form with a warning instead to get the Django exception error message?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model forms validation should take care of this and raise the validation error. But you have excluded the `user` field from form, which is part of `unique_together` constraint, hence its not getting verified. Ref [`validate_unique`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique)

You can try changing the view code to add `user` field in posted data and then instantiate the form.

Or better way would be add hidden user field in the form, so that its available in `request.POST` and the validation works as required.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rohan, I found the hidden field solution the best: now I correctly get back my form with the error message: `Shape file with this Name and User already exists`.
Here's my modified code to get things work:

- **forms.py**

  ```
  class UploadForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = ShapeFile
          fields = ('name','user','srid','file','color_table')
          widgets = {'srid': TextInput(), 'user': HiddenInput()}
  ```
- **views.py**

  ```
  @login_required
  def index(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
          if form.is_valid():
              req = request.POST
              sridVal = form.cleaned_data['srid'].pk
              shpVal = form.cleaned_data['name']

              # The final table name is something like 'mutant_celeryPy2_123_salzburg_lc'
              end_table_name = request.user.username + "_" + shpVal + '_lc'

              # Creates a table, otherwise return the retrieved one
              model_def, created = ModelDefinition.objects.get_or_create(
                  app_label='celeryPy2',
                  object_name=end_table_name,
                  defaults=dict(
                     bases=(BaseDefinition(base=GeoModel),),
                     fields=(GeometryFieldDefinition(name='the_geom', srid=sridVal),
                             SmallIntegerFieldDefinition(name='cat'),)
                  )
              )
              obj = form.save(commit=False)
              obj.model_definition = model_def
              obj.save()
              messages.success(request, 'Shapefile upload succesful!')
              return HttpResponse('Stored!')
          else:
              print "Upload shapefile form is invalid!!!"
      else:
          form = UploadForm(initial={'user': request.user})

      return render_to_response('celeryPy2/index.html',
                                {'form': form,},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```