# Django: validating unique_together constraints in a ModelForm with excluded fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form:

```
class CourseStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CourseStudent
        exclude = ['user']
```

for a model with some complicated requirements:

```
class CourseStudent(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester)
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    grade = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('semester', 'block', 'user'), 
            ('user','course','grade'),
        )
```

I want the new object to use the current logged in user for CourseStudent.user:

```
class CourseStudentCreate(CreateView):
    model = CourseStudent
    form_class = CourseStudentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('quests:quests')


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CourseStudentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

This works, however, because the user is not part of the form, it misses the validation that Django would otherwise do with the unique_together constraints.

How can I get my form and view to use Django's validation on these constraints rather than having to write my own?

I though of passing the user in a hidden field in the form (rather than exclude it), but that appears to be unsafe (i.e. the user value could be changed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `form.instance.user` in `form_valid` is too late, because the form has already been validated by then. Since that's the only custom thing your `form_valid` method does, you should remove it.

You could override [`get_form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_form_kwargs), and pass in a `CourseStudent` instance with the user already set:

```
class CourseStudentCreate(CreateView):
    model = CourseStudent
    form_class = CourseStudentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('quests:quests')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['instance'] = CourseStudent(user=self.request.user)
        return kwargs
```

That isn't enough to make it work, because the form validation skips the unique together constraints that refer to the `user` field. The solution is to override the model form's `full_clean()` method, and explicitly call [`validate_unique()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) on the model. Overriding the `clean` method (as you would normally do) doesn't work, because the instance hasn't been populated with values from the form at that point.

```
class CourseStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CourseStudent
        exclude = ['user']

    def full_clean(self):
        super(CourseStudentForm, self).full_clean()
        try:
            self.instance.validate_unique()
        except forms.ValidationError as e:
            self._update_errors(e)
```

Comment: Using this code, I am getting this error:
TypeError at /courses/create/
`ModelFormMetaclass object argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType`

Comment: I had missed out the return statement in `get_form_kwargs`, please can you try again. If you still get an error, please update your question with the full traceback -- one line often isn't enough to see what's going on.

Comment: (thanks for the help)
The form works, but doesn't validate the model:

IntegrityError at /courses/create/
`UNIQUE constraint failed: courses_coursestudent.semester_id, courses_coursestudent.block_id, courses_coursestudent.user_id`

Comment: Ok, I think I have got it to work, by overriding `full_clean` instead of `clean`. It's quite hacky, so maybe there's a cleaner approach that I'm missing.

Comment: Like magic!  Thank you for the detailed explanation too, really helps with learning this stuff.

How would you compare your method with doing this to achieve the same effect:

use hidden widget for user field and pre-populate to current user, then in view's form_valid, check that form.user is still same as request.user before saving to db (to prevent security problem)?

Comment: You are right to worry about the danger of the user changing the value of the hidden field. Doing validation in `form_valid` isn't ideal, because it's separate from the rest of the validation code. Personally, I prefer the approach of setting the value to the logged in user, rather than checking that the submitted value hasn't been tampered with. Having said that, if you've got time, give your way a go. If you get it working that way and you prefer it, go for it. Choose the approach that you think will be easier for you to understand and maintain in future.

Comment: At this point yours is working, so I'm sticking with that! I was just curious.

Comment: Great answer. Instead of using the "private" method `self._update_errors(e)`, wouldn't it be more appropriate to call `self.add_error(field=None, error=e)`? (With `field=None` it will become a [non_field_error](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.non_field_errors))

Comment: @djvg yes, it would probably be better to use `self.add_error()`. I can't see a good reason for why I used `self._update_errors(e)` when I wrote the answer, since `add_error` was added in Django 1.7 in 2014.

Comment: @Alasdair why Django does not automatically calls `validate_unique()` for admin models?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, please check. Requesting feedback/suggestions.
(Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923826/django-how-do-i-validate-unique-together-from-within-the-model) SO post.)

1) Modify POST request to send the excluded_field.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  obj = get_object_or_404(Model, id=id)
  request.POST = request.POST.copy()
  request.POST['excluded_field'] = obj
  return super(Model, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

2) Update form's clean method with the required validation

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    product = cleaned_data.get('included_field')
    component = self.data['excluded_field']

    if Model.objects.filter(included_field=included_field, excluded_field=excluded_field).count() > 0:
        del cleaned_data['included_field']
        self.add_error('included_field', 'Combination already exists.')

    return cleaned_data
```