# How do I make an IntegerField get autoincrement and not editable?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a field called "number", and would like it to be autoincrement and not editable.

I have a system that has multiple users. Each user can register a document that follows an ordinal sequence. Each user can only create as many documents as he wants, but each document has its number generated in order, and should never be repeated.

I tried using:

```
number = models.IntegerField (unique = True)
```

However, it occurs that if another user has already created a document with that number, another user can not create it.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    responsible = models.ForeignKey(Responsible, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    from = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    work_from = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    text = models.TextField()
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Just a quick sidenote: you cannot use a language keyword (`from`) as a field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unique_together` to allow different users to have the same `number`:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('responsible', 'number'),]
```

The best way to get the number to increment depends on the database you are using. The simplests solution is to get the last number:

```
last_document = Document.objects.filter(responsible=responsible).order_by('number').last()
```

If that returns a document, you can add one to the number. This has the disadvantage of race conditions if the same user creates multiple documents at once.

Databases like PostgreSQL allow you to [create sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createsequence.html). The disadvantage of this is that you can end up with gaps if the values are not used.

Comment: Race condition should be tolerable as long as the constraint is enforced at the database level. Simply catch the integrity error from django and retry. I'd still go for a sequence if gaps are allowed.

Comment: It worked. However, it returns an integrity error. How do I handle this error so that a message is displayed on the form screen?

Comment: Catch the integrity error in a try except block. I can’t be more specific, because you haven’t shown the code that gives the error.

Comment: This is code: https://github.com/daniloarodrigues/oficio/blob/master/oficio/views.py#L37-L55

Comment: This is error: 
UNIQUE constraint failed: oficio_oficio.responsavel_id, oficio_oficio.numero

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260785/) should help.

Comment: I got it sorted out. I created the Meta with unique_together, captured the integrity error, and added the exceptions.